# How to upgrade new version of Eclipse instead of using new downloaded package?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars, eclipse-oxygen

I am looking for steps to upgrade my current Eclipse version (**Mars**) to latest version (**Oxygen**) because I have been using Mars for past long time so that contains all the settings, plugins and all the histories so I would like to retain the same and also upgrade to new version.

Is this possible?

Note: It can be any type of Eclipse for any kind of development like Java, C/C++, PHP, JavaScript and Testers.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. In ***Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Site*** make sure that the ***Latest Eclipse Simultaneous Release*** (or *Latest Eclipse Release*) update site exists and **is checked**. Otherwise (in older versions or when this update site has been removed in newer versions), click *Add...*, enter the update site location **`https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest`** and click *OK*.
2. ***Help > Check for Updates***

See also [Eclipse Wiki - *FAQ How do I upgrade Eclipse IDE?*](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F)

Comment: Yes,  you are correct, I can see the site location for Mars (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/mars), thanks @howlger

Comment: Unfortunately the software update mechanism may download at abysmal rates making this a pain.  Much faster to download a new, and import settings from the old.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Updating is not slower than downloading a new package and you don't lose a plug-in that you have installed. If you observe _"abysmal"_ download rates on update, [please report this as an bug to Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Community&component=Servers).

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What did you do years ago that didn't help?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen _m2e-wtp_ was not an Eclipse project at this time. So you couldn't download it from Eclipse at that time. The Eclipse Marketplace lists also software that has to be downloaded from somewhere else. Adding an update site and _Help > Check for Updates_ are not related to the Eclipse Marketplace client/server.

Comment: Say for a feature like this - https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.7/jdt.php#step-show-methodresult, is there a way to tell what update you need to install for this feature? I don't want to install every update from Oxygen

Comment: @committedandroider Yes, in _Help > Install New Software..._ work with `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/latest` and choose _Programming Languages > Eclipse Java Development Tools_ only. But as far as I known, also in the _Update_ dialog you can choose the items to upgrade.

Comment: As of release 2021-12 (and perhaps earlier releases) the update site is called "Latest Eclipse Simulteneous Release", not "Latest Eclipse Release"

Answer (score 8):

This might be useful.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F

There are some package structural changes from Eclipse Neon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think updating from Update Site will update the eclipse.ini file: you need to fix it.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library    plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.500.v20170531-1133
```

However, if you simply want to keep your preferences and your plugin, I suggest you to use Eclipse for that:

In Oxygen.1 (or the updated Eclipse), you can install feature/plugins

1. using an existing installation (go to *File > Import* then select *Install > From Existing Installation)
2. using an exported software item (go to *File > Import* then select *Install > Install Software Items from File)

For the second option, you need to export it first on the previous Eclipse using *File > Export > Install > Installed Software Items to File*.

**Note:** the Eclipse directory store little configuration (at least, it store the known workspaces/update site). This [link here](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html#locations) might be of interest.

Comment: Updating from p2 update site updates also the `eclipse.ini` file (via the so-called [Eclipse Touchpoint Actions](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_actions_touchpoints.html)).

Comment: Ok. That must explain why I often have a lot of duplicate parameters in my eclipse.ini :o