# Cannot install EclEmma in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, installation, eclemma

I tried to install EclEmma and Eclipse Indigo won't let me. I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: EclEmma Java Code Coverage 3.0.0.201706140232 
(org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group 3.0.0.201706140232)
Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 
1.4.2.20120213-0813 (epp.package.jee 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
Eclipse Workbench User Guide 3.7.0.v20110601-0800 
(org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 3.7.0.v20110601-0800)
Eclipse Workbench User Guide 3.7.1.r372_v20111202 
(org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 3.7.1.r372_v20111202)
Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.5.0.v20150603-2358 
(org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.5.0.v20150603-2358)
Eclipse Workbench User Guide 4.5.1.v20150819-1130 
(org.eclipse.platform.doc.user 4.5.1.v20150819-1130)
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.4.2.20120213-0813 
(epp.package.jee 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.4.2.20120213-0813]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: EclEmma Java Code Coverage 3.0.0.201706140232 
(org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group 3.0.0.201706140232)
To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.8.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.4.2.20120213-0813 
(org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.4.2.20120213-0813)
To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-
PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-
PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 
3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
To: org.eclipse.platform.doc.user [3.7.1.r372_v20111202]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 4.5.0.v20150603-2358  
(org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.5.0.v20150603-2358)
To: org.eclipse.platform.doc.user [4.5.0.v20150603-2358]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 4.5.1.v20150904-0015 
(org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.5.1.v20150904-0015)
To: org.eclipse.platform.doc.user [4.5.1.v20150819-1130]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Eclipse Platform 4.5.2.v20160212-1500 
(org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.5.2.v20160212-1500)
To: org.eclipse.platform.doc.user [4.5.1.v20150819-1130]
```

What am I supposed to do or uninstall? I think it is another plug in or something that's causing a conflict

Comment: Eclipse Indigo (3.7) is too old. The EclEmma web site says 3.8 or newer (Eclipse Oxygen - 4.7 is current).

Comment: @greg-449 is there a way to update eclipse without losing anything?

Comment: @AwesomeGuy Yes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250 (the Java packages of Eclipse Oxygen already contains EclEmma)

Comment: I dont get it... whyyyy use old releases???