# Open Shift 3 not working in Eclipse Keplar

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, openshift

I'm using Eclipse Keplar and I've updated to the latest jboss oxygen tools. when i try to create a new connection via openshift explorer it's still showing me the old interface and not letting me select the server type as described here: https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-eclipse-jboss-tools-openshift-online-3/

what am I missing? followed those steps exactly and still getting openshift 2 connection dialog.

UPDATE: Even when trying to force it to connect to server url: https://console.starter-ca-central-1.openshift.com it still is trying to connect to v2 and not v3.

Comment: Do you mean Eclipse Kepl**e**r, the Eclipse version that is more than 4 years old?

Comment: Says it's supported. I've been using it for openshift 2. Nothing has changed besides pointing to new server. so would updating the eclipse version do it?

Comment: [It would be worth a try.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250)

Comment: You're also likely having issues following a blog for OpenShift 3 connections, but trying to use an OpenShift 2 connection. Could you tell us what server exactly you're trying to connect to?

Comment: I updated JBoss tools and it's still pointing to v2. How do I get it to point to v3?