# how to upgrade eclipse in appcelerator studio

Tags: eclipse, appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

How do you upgrade the Eclipse version in Appcelerator Studio from 4.4.2 to Neon or Oxygen? I am working on PyDev projects and getting the error please update your Eclipse to 4.6 or later.

Simply adding the URL to the installation source allows add-ons but does not upgrade the Eclipse Platform. I already have Oxygen loaded on my development station. Is there a way to use that version rather than the built in version

Platform OSX 10.13, Python 2.7, Appcelerator Studio 4.10.0.201709271713, PyDev 6.0.0.2017xxxx

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250

Answer (score 1):

You can't upgrade Appcelerator Studio eclipse base version. Studio 4.10.0 comes with the Eclipse 4.4.2

However, it's planned for future release https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7565

Please provide more details about your problem in the above ticket.