# Eclipse null pointer exception when invoking JFace plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, centos7, jface

I have eclipse Mars on CentOS and I can't reach "java build path", "deployment assembly", "project facets" and some other tabs in my project's properties.
A `Problems occurred after invoking code from plug-in "org.eclipse.jface".` error windows comes up so I attached the screenshot of its details.
I searched and tried a lot of solutions (including cleaning projects, switching workspaces, create a new project, removing .classpath, .project and .settings, starting eclipse with --clean, clean IDE install, changing JDK), but none worked so far. Did anyone beat this?

[image]

EDIT: Exception stack trace text

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.gtk_switch_page(TabFolder.java:490)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1994)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4723)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_widget_show(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_widget_show(OS.java:14720)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabFolder.createItem(TabFolder.java:274)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.createWidget(TabItem.java:123)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TabItem.<init>(TabItem.java:75)
at org.eclipse.jst.servlet.ui.internal.WebModuleDependencyPageProvider.createRootControl(WebModuleDependencyPageProvider.java:77)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.ui.propertypage.ModuleAssemblyRootPage.createContents(ModuleAssemblyRootPage.java:204)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferencePage.createControl(PreferencePage.java:241)
at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.ui.propertypage.ModuleAssemblyRootPage.createControl(ModuleAssemblyRootPage.java:346)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPageControl(PreferenceDialog.java:1450)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$13.run(PreferenceDialog.java:1217)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1209)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9$1.run(PreferenceDialog.java:675)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:670)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:877)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:874)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1243)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1269)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:259)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1$2.run(OpenStrategy.java:440)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3794)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3433)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.PropertyDialogAction.run(PropertyDialogAction.java:157)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4481)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1327)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3819)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3430)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

**EDIT2: Thanks everyone for helping. The way I solved this: update eclipse like @howgler said, import to new workspace and clean every project. If needed, import to another workspace. Do not forget to backup old workspace, as it may change due to version differences.**

Comment: Please don't attach screenshots of your stacktraces, instead copy-paste them her :) Also, when you say "I searched and tried a lot of solutions [...] but none worke"d", you may want to precise what you've tried so far -- so we don't give you the same answers

Comment: Edited. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [known bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=495374) has been fixed in Eclipse Oxygen.0 (4.7.0).

An [**update**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250) from the no longer maintained Eclipse Mars (4.5) **to Eclipse Oxygen** (4.7) should solve your problem.

Comment: No luck. Same error plus a few from org.eclipse.jst.j2ee plugin.

Comment: Can you please describe how the error can be reproduced in Oxygen.1a with a new workspace?

Comment: Downloaded Oxygen, extracted it, made a copy of my workspace beacuse of the upgrade differences, selected workspace copy as workspace. On launch and this is my "welcome screen".
https://imgur.com/a/JepUz

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue by starting with a new workspace and importing your projects from the old to the new workspace?

Comment: Exactly which file does "Downloaded Oxygen" mean?

Comment: Importing to an empty workspace looks to be working with still some errors. Maybe I can work this out from here.

Downloaded Eclipse Oxygen Java EE linux from
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/1a/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz&mirror_id=1215

Comment: @rtrigo If this works, you can try in your old workspace to move or to delete the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi` file which stores the window layout and then open the old workspace with the new Eclipse.