# Reinstalling Eclipse without losing projects

Tags: eclipse

Just a quick question, if I reinstall Eclipse, will I lose work that I have on the application, or will it stay in my files? Does deleting the app delete the folder made for eclipse? Thanks!

Comment: Projects and preferences are stored in the Workspace (see _File > Switch Workspace > Other..._). Instead of reinstalling you can also upgrade to the latest version of Eclipse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your workspaces, if you have your projects in a workspace, you can save the folder and later when you reinstall eclipse import the folder. that's the better way.

Answer (score 0):

you will not lose your work it will stay in workspace folder. Dontworry.