# Error occured while lunching Eclipse (log file)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to Java. Currently I am facing problem with eclipse. I am unable to open Eclipse. I have tried to solve it by downloading the latest Eclipse but it does not help me. Here I am providing the log file. I can't understand where the problem located.
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93365c156bd43fd6830a1aa63a5148e5

At present i am using windows 10.

Comment: This is caused by Eclipse Mars (4.5.0) with Java 9. I recommend [updating to Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250). Alternatively, edit eclipse.ini as follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370112/6505250

Comment: Eclipse Mars isn't the latest version by a long way. Use Eclipse Oxygen.1a