# How do I fix this error log I get when launching eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

A few days ago I set up my Eclipse to use JavaFX for the first time. Eclipse has been set up on my computer for several months and worked on my computer with no issues. Today I tried to launch Eclipse and was unable to. The first exception in the log file is below. Full log file at: https://pastebin.com/NKLgdfhG

Any ideas?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 0 2018-09-11 19:48:16.228
!MESSAGE Error retrieving proposal text.
Display string:
No Proposals
Pattern:
out.println("
!STACK 0
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 13
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.getPatternMatchRule(AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.java:919)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.getStyledDisplayString(AbstractJavaCompletionProposal.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.handleSetData(CompletionProposalPopup.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.access$8(CompletionProposalPopup.java:844)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$3.handleEvent(CompletionProposalPopup.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1079)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1103)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1088)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.checkData(Table.java:1189)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.wmNotifyChild(Table.java:6981)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.wmNotify(Control.java:5869)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.wmNotify(Composite.java:2025)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.WM_NOTIFY(Control.java:5423)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4899)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1657)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2199)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5191)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4941)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:6118)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5191)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.SendMessage(OS.java:3333)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.select(Table.java:3519)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.setSelection(Table.java:5256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.selectProposal(CompletionProposalPopup.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.setProposals(CompletionProposalPopup.java:1179)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup$1.run(CompletionProposalPopup.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4213)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3820)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:680)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1499)
```

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=496545

Comment: I don't understand what the relevance of this is. It's a link to a discussion about a really old eclipse bug which was fixed in 2016?

Comment: According to your error message "Error retrieving proposal text" , so you can try to find any relate bug to figure out what may cause this error , such as plugin update.

Comment: This looks much more like bug [487268](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=487268) but again that was fixed some time ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned log entry happened in September 2018. The last entries are inserted at the end of the log, not at the beginning.

Probably the **upgrade from Java 8 to 11**, which was done between April 8 and 13, 2019 on your system, is causing the problem (Java 11 does not contain JavaFX anymore):

```
!SESSION 2019-04-08 20:31:32.915 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.1.M20171009-0410
java.version=1.8.0_161
```

[...]

```
!SESSION 2019-04-13 00:34:34.112 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.7.1.M20171009-0410
java.version=11.0.2
```

**[Running Eclipse with Java 8](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)** should solve your issue. If you want to run Eclipse with Java 11, you have to [upgrade Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250) first (you are four releases behind).