# How to resolve "Error: Could not find or load main class FirstProgram" while running OpenCV Java in Eclipse?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, opencv

I have started learning OpenCV Java and this is the program I have written to test the OpenCV setup:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
public class FirstProgram 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        Mat mat = Mat.eye(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1);
        System.out.println(mat.dump());
    }
}
```

But on running this, Eclipse shows the error: 
"*Error: Could not find or load main class FirstProgram
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FirstProgram*"

I have already setup the [user libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiwYu.jpg) and added the libraries to the [project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHTdg.jpg). (Screenshots linked)

How do I resolve this issue ?

- OpenCV version: 4.2.0
- Eclipse: 2019-03
- JDK: 13

Comment: Eclipse 2019-03 (released March, 2019)  is too old for Java 13 (released September, 2019). Please [upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades) (the current version is Eclipse 2020-03).

Comment: Are there any entries for the project in the Problems View?

Comment: @howlger It seems you were right. It's working now that I have upgraded the IDE. Thanks.

Comment: @nitind The problem was resolved by upgrading the IDE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse 2019-03 (released March 2019) is too old for Java 13 (released September 2019).

Please [upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250) to the current version (currently, Eclipse 2020-03).