# How can i do git pull at MissingObjectException error?

Tags: git, eclipse, pull

I have a project at Eclipse. Suddenly It occurs Git errors when I pull from remote repo.
Git reset was useless. and As I do it again after all project removed. Too sad, it is not working.
How can i fix this?
If you give me a hand, I really really appreciate to you. thx.

[image]

Comment: Which JGit version do you have exactly (see _Help > About...: Installation Details_)?

Comment: howlger, thank you for your concern. JGit verision is org.eclipse.jgit-4.5.3.201708160445-r.

Comment: SpringBoot version is 1.5.22.RELEASE and Gradle project. thanks

Comment: Your EGit/JGit and probably also Eclipse/STS is very old. You probably face a bug that has been already fixed (in the bug tracker I found some `MissingObjectException` errors, that have been fixed in the last years). [So, please upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250) and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much. Okay. I upgrade and try again :)