# Eclipse in Debug view does not refresh

Tags: eclipse

Eclipse in debug view does not refresh correctly as you can see on the picture. [image]

It only refreshes the debug view after I move the cursor up or down. Step over or Step Into commands do not fix the refresh problem.

I am running Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers on MacOS

Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) Build id: 20190917-1200

Also, when I set the cursor above a variable in the debug view it does not show its content in the rectangle that opens below. The rectangle remains empty. This used to work before.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: This looks like you updated macOS to Big Sur, but missed to update Eclipse as well.

Comment: Thx @howlger
When updating I get "An error occured while uninstalling"- >

An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.platform_root 4.13.0.v20190916-1323 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/.eclipseproduct failed.
File that was copied to backup could not be deleted: /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/.eclipseproduct

Any advice?

Comment: Try reinstalling instead of upgrading (I'm not familiar with macOS and don't know if there is another way in this case; might also be related to Big Sur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you have an **outdated Eclipse** that was released before Big Sur, and not yet Eclipse 2020-12 with fixes for Big Sure (maybe [Eclipse bug 569147](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=569147) or one of these [Big Sure bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/showdependencytree.cgi?id=565691&hide_resolved=0) which are already fixed).

**[Upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250) or [reinstall](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) Eclipse** to get rid of these UI glitches.

Comment: Thanks @howlger. The upgrade does not work for me. I will try the reinstall. Will the new version of Eclipse use the Eclipse Workspace configuration from before? I can see it installs itself in a new directory /Users/asusti/eclipse/java-2020-12

Comment: Yes, the workspace configuration/preferences from before will be used.

Comment: Thanks @howlger. It worked like a charm. Upgrading Eclipse to Eclipse 2020-12 fixed all the UI glitches I had after the Big Sur OS update. The workspace configuration/preferences were preserved.