# i'm having an error while trying to install e(fx)clipse Eclipse plug-in on Eclipse from Market Place

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-plugin

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE 3.7.0.202010120832 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.202010120832)
Missing requirement: JDT UI Tooling for JavaFX 3.7.0.202010120832 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.ui 3.7.0.202010120832) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.emf.databinding 1.2.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - Basic 3.7.0.202010120832 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.202010120832)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.fx.ide.jdt.ui [3.7.0.202010120832,3.7.0.202010120832]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: e(fx)clipse - IDE 3.7.0.202010120832 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 3.7.0.202010120832)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.fx.ide.basic.feature.feature.group [3.7.0.202010120832,3.7.0.202010120832]
```

i get that it asks for me to install something but i don't really get it, everything is supposed to be up to date i tried to update eclipse and i have 17 java SDK, what is missing?

Comment: openjfx.io have a guide to [getting started with JavaFX using Eclipse](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse).

Comment: With which result do you tried to update Eclipse (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273081/6505250 )? What does _Help > About Eclipse IDE_ show?

Comment: You need to fix the title to this question. This is not about installing JavaFX, it is about installing the e(fx)clipse Eclipse plug-in.

Comment: done sorry for that

Comment: i updated eclipse from help---->check for updates

Comment: Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0)
Build id: 20211202-1639
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2021.  All rights reserved. Eclipse and the Eclipse logo are trademarks of the Eclipse Foundation, Inc., https://www.eclipse.org/. The Eclipse logo cannot be altered without Eclipses permission. Eclipse logos are provided for use under the Eclipse logo and trademark guidelines, https://www.eclipse.org/logotm/. Oracle and Java are trademarks or registered trademarks of Oracle and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Comment: so i think i'm sure i'm on the newest update of this month